# Is there a react native component with which I can build a chart (day x hour of the day) and show an image at every "point"?

Tags: react-native

Is there a react native component with which I can build a chart (day x hour of the day) and show an image at every "point", like the example below?

I am trying with [react-native-svg-chart](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts) but it doesn't "load" images on top of the chart.

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VictoryNative (React Native version of Victory Charts) is excellent, and allows you to render arbitrary components as your data points: [Custom Components](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/custom-components/)

Comment: Thanks @Kai, this component is great! I am still struggling with formatting axis and adding links to the data, but I already managed to get to something similar to the image I posted above. :)